# Facing problem to download Hex file to STM32 using Command line

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, flash, hex

I managed to write a script for flashing hex file into STM microcontroller.

`"C:\Program Files\STMicroelectronics\STM32 ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK Utility\ST-Link_CLI.exe" -c UR FREQ=80 -ME -P "C:\Usr\someHex.hex" 0x08000000 -V -TVolt`

Although it is showing that the process has completed and flashed the program. I can not see anything when I manually connect to the STM32 ST-Link Utility.

[image: 1]

Although the command line is showing that the HEX file has flashed properly but STM32 ST-Link shows that the script did not flash the hex file properly.

[image: 2]

Can anyone recommend me the solution?

Comment: What does your hex file contain? How big it is? Why the address reported by programmer is 0x08001000, does the hex start at that address or 0x08000000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that your program starts at 0x08001000 probably because of a bootloader so if you want to see what you wrote you have to start reading from that point because you are showing a few bytes starting at 0x08000000 and they have not been written.